# MSP430 TI while loop duration

Tags: c, microprocessors

I am programming a simple program on the TI MSP430.

I have a counter set up in C:

```
while (P1IN & BIT1)
{
counter++;
}
```

So when the pin is high, it counts up by one. I am wondering how long this takes?

I need to do some calculations with counter and need the duration of one while loop. In other words, say counter = 1234 in the end, how can I get a value of seconds?

How can I get this? Should I export the ASM code and see how long each instruction set takes? This seems tedious.

Comment: if you are reluctant to look at the assembly then you can run this loop from another loop with a large loop counter , measure (log) time before and after the loop and divide by the counter to see the time taken by the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
1. Toggle any free port pin at the start and end of the loop and monitor the duration on CRO(If you have necessary equipment).

OR

2.Look into disassembly listing(ASM code),read instruction manual and based on CPU clock calculate the loop time.

Comment: Yes I have CR0 on the MSP but how would I modify my while loop to get the timing?

Comment: @renegade : Do not modify while loop,Make a free pin high before while loop and make low again after the while loop,You will get the whole loop execution time. If you want to single loop execution time,you need to look into ASM code for while loop.